# JSHint error on Ember build

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jshint, broccolijs

I am in the process of upgrading an Ember application from version 2.4.3 to 2.9.1. The application builds successfully, but I get a list of 42 versions of the following JSHint error; each starting with a different file name

```
unit/services/tracker-test.js: line 0, col 0, Incompatible values for the 'esversion' and 'esnext' linting options. (0% scanned).
```

My `.jshintrc` file contains

```
...
"esnext": true,
"esversion": 6,
...
```

What is coursing the errors?

Comment: If you're using Microsoft's VSCode JSHint, make sure it's updated. This used to be a bug, before April 20, on their Issues. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jshint/issues/18

Comment: I am not using VSCode even though the error seems to be identical with mine.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [jshint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext), `esnext` is deprecated:

> Warning This option has been deprecated and will be removed in the
>   next major release of JSHint. Use `esversion: 6` instead.

It is meaningless to set both `"esnext": true` option and `"esversion": 6` option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to remove the `esnext` option, but it did not help. The fact is that I was not aware of the `.jshintrc` located in `/tests/` with the same options as the one in the root directory. I changed the options, and now everything works.

Comment: Yes, there are another `.jshintrc` files at `tests` and `blueprints` directories.

Answer (score 1):

So I realised that a `.jshintrc` file also exists in the `tests/` directory. Ykaragold wrote that the `esnext` option is deprecated, so removing this option from both `.jshintrc` and `tests/.jshintrc` worked for me.